# Proving if Something is a Group and if it is Cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I came across this question while studying for abstract alg:

Let $A$ be a binary structure given by multiplication mod 20 on {$4, 8, 12, 16$}. Is $A$ a group? If so, is it cyclic?

My thinking is that it is a group since it doesn't contain the identity element (group doesn't contain 0.) Am I correct? If not, can someone help me through this problem? I don't think I understand group theory and cyclic/non-cyclic very well. Thank you.

Comment: You right ! It's not a group for the reason you said.

Comment: One minor correction: under multiplication, the identity is $1$, not $0$. Otherwise, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\times_{20} & 4 & 8 & 12 & 16 \\ \hline
4 & 16 & 12 & 8 & 4 \\
8 & 12 & 4 & 16 & 8 \\
12 & 8 & 16 & 4 & 12 \\
16 & 4 & 8 & 12 & 16
\end{array}$$

Working out the multiplication table, we see that $\{4,8,12,16\}$ does form a group under multiplication modulo $20$ with identity element $16$. To deduce whether the group is cyclic, you should check whether there is an element that generates the full group.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is actually a group. The identity element is $16$. You can test and see that any other element, multiplied by $16$ ($mod 20$), would result in the same element. Also, $4$ is its own inverse and $12$ and $8$ make a pair of inverses.

It is cyclic as well. The element $12$ is a generator of the group.

Comment: How did you find 12 as the generator of the group?

Comment: start with 12, as the first element, and multiply it by 12 (mod 20) to get the second element. Then do the same process with the second element to get a third one and continue it. If the sequence is equal to A, then it is cyclic.

Comment: Is there any general way to find the generator of a group without using trial-and-error method? Just curious. Like for instance, is there some kind of "algebraic method" or anything instead of checking to see if each element is the generator? Thanks!

Comment: I think there is no easy, general method to find generators of a group. One way is to find an isomorphic group, to the one that you have, for which you know if it is cyclic or not. If you find such a group, you know if your group is cyclic or not. At the same time, the isomorphism maps a generator of one group to a generator of the other one.